# Counting Pairs of Disjoint Hyperplanes in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

How many distinct pairs of disjoint hyperplanes of size $q^{n-1}$ exist in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$?

Initially I had just thought to pick n points to define a hyperplane, and divide by the number of ways to pick such points, that is:

$\frac{q^n \choose n}{q^{n-1} \choose n}$

From there each hyperplane would presumably have $q-1$ disjoint neighbors giving:

$\frac{(q-1){q^n \choose n}}{2{q^{n-1} \choose n}}$

However, I realize this does not deal with sets of points which are coplanar. This number then is a lower bound, as these coplanar sets are not counted enough times. Is there a way to get around this? Knowing the number of sets of n non-coplanar points would presumably do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call disjoint hyperplanes *parallel*. For a given hyperplane there
will be $q-1$ planes parallel to it. There are $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$
hyperplanes through the origin (why?) and so $q(q^n-1)/(q-1)$ hyperplanes overall. When counting pairs of disjoint hyperplanes I suppose
one has to decide whether one is counting ordered or unordered pairs...

Answer (score 1):

For selecting the first and second points, you have $q^n$ and $q^n-1$ options: anything except for the same thing. For selecting the third point, you can again pick any of the $q^n$, except for the $q$ points on the line defined -- so that you have $q^n-q$ options. For the fourth point, you have $q^n-n^2$, because you're excluding the $n^2$ points generated by the first three. And so on. But this does indeed produce the same plane many times, and reducing the multiple counting is tricky.

An easier method is to recognize that a hyperplane is defined by its normal vector, and its position along that vector. This can be any nonzero length-$n$ vector of $F_q$ values, but of course scaling the normal vector leaves the plane unchanged. There are $q^n$ vectors, then $q^n-1$ nonzero ones, and $q-1$ ways we can rescale it, so that there are $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ normal vectors. Then there are $q$ places "along" this vector to place the plane. So there are

$$\frac{q(q^n-1)}{q-1}$$

distinct hyperplanes. If $q$ is even of course these can be perfectly paired up, and so there are

$$\frac{q(q^n-1)}{2(q-1)}$$

pairs. If $q$ is odd, then all-but-one with a given normal vector can be paired up, so that there are $(q-1)/2$ pairs with a given normal vector, or

$$\frac{(q-1)(q^n-1)}{2(q-1)} = \frac{q^n-1}{2}$$

pairs that can be made simultaneously.